# Custom Tabs with Line below in CSS

Tags: html, css, tabs, customization

I'm designing an application wherein i want to have tabs like below

[image]

But currently i'm seeing something like below (covered by box)

[image]

I searched the web for a similar design but i didn't find anything. Could you help to achieve the same?

**Update**

with `border-bottom: 2px solid blue;` i can get the blue line below, but the highlighted box is still appearing as shown below. I want to avoid that as well.

[image]

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: You can try `border-bottom`.

Comment: @xmaster , it is a application provided tab. With UI i can create a tab without any code. But i can also customize with custom CSS.

Comment: then I would include something like this `border-bottom: 2px solid blue;`  combined with `:active`

Comment: @JoohongTan , @xmaster Thanks with `border-bottom` i can get the below line as in the picture. But still the gray highlighted box is appearing. How to avoid that.  have edited the question

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy we need to see your code for that

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy but try this in your code `background-color: transparent` and if necessary add `!important` this after transparent

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy share your HTM/CSS code, I can give you exact code :)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.tabs {
  position: relative;   
  min-height: 200px; /* This part sucks */
  clear: both;
  margin: 45px 0 25px;
  background: white;
  color: #41C0ED;
  font-weight:bold;
  padding: 5px;
}
.tab {
  float: left;
   
}
.tab label {
  background: #fff; 
  padding: 10px; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
  margin-left: -1px; 
  position: relative;
  left: 1px; 
  top: -29px;
 
}
.tab [type=radio] {
  display: none;   
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .6s linear;
  opacity: 0;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #308AC2;
  z-index: 2;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
    
   <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
       <label for="tab-1">Tab One</label>
       
       <div class="content">
           
       </div> 
   </div>
    
   <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-2">Tab Two</label>
       
       <div class="content">
           
       </div> 
   </div>
    
    <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-3">Tab Three</label>
     
       <div class="content">
          
       </div> 
   </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: if I were you I would change `min-height: 200px` to vh (use viewport)

Answer (score 0):

You can use :
`background-color: transparent !important;`

Comment: As a rule, you should try to avoid using `!important`

Comment: @xmaster okay but why not answering yourself then?

Comment: Do you try it and how about problem ?